# Django. How to implement a logic to initiate a delete time counter or countdown in django models to delete objects automatically?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

Hello guys how can I implement a logic in django to delete a coupon automatically after 2 days from the time the user has opted to delete his post.?

I have this view which has the normal delete function. but how to make changes in this to have this deleted automatically after 2 or 3 days from the database and not immediately.?

view

```
class DeletePostView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, BSModalDeleteView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'posts/delete_post.html'
    success_message = 'Deleted'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('posts:myhome')

    def test_func(self):
        post = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == post.user:
            return True
        return False
```

If its difficult to implement in class based view, please do let me know how to implement that logic with fbv.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could create a separate model that holds the time and id of the post when the user deleted it. Then using a cronjob, you check every day for each of the objects for that model if the 2 or 3 days is passed.

For example

```
class DeletedPostsModel(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

in the cronjob you check if the created field is x days less the current date. if so, delete the post. The cronjob should call a custom command that handles the delete logic. read about it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-management-commands/)

in your `DeletePostView`, override the delete method where you create the DeletedPostsModel and set the current post.